# Disable mod_security by requested URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-security

I use **mod_security** with Apache 2.4. On this platform we have an ecommerce system using the following URL for its administrative tools:

**http://www.tld.com/en/backend**

**I want to achive to goals:**

1. Access to /en/backend only possible from local network (works already, done with rewriteRules
2. mod_security should be disabled in the backend

And no, "backend" is no physical existing directory, it´s an MVC mapping :)
So I´m looking for **some kind of combination between mod_rewrite and mod_security**.

Anybody any idea? :)

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 7):

It's quite simple: put the exclude rules **right after** SecRuleEngine directive

```
SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly
SecRule REQUEST_BASENAME "@beginsWith /url_to_exclude" "id:1,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"
```

of course, you can use different operators instead of `@beginsWith` - just like they are described in the [official manual](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#Operators)

Comment: What is id:1 in "id:1,ctl:ruleEngine=Off" ?

Comment: it's a directive that disables the IDS for the **specific** URL

Comment: My link fire many rule IDs, what effective way to bypass all  rules?

Comment: use the bypass rule from my answer as **the very first** one - it should solve your problem

Comment: Thank you, I have other problem: SecRule REQUEST_BASENAME "@beginsWith /url_to_A" "id:1,ctl:ruleEngine=Off" and SecRule REQUEST_BASENAME "@beginsWith /url_to_B" "id:1,ctl:ruleEngine=Off". Modsecurity did not allow me to add these 2 rules with same ID

Comment: it's not a problem to make the ID unique - it's what the id is actually proposed for

Answer (score 0):

"Modsecurity did not allow me to add these 2 rules with same ID"

Because each rule must have its own unique number.
Rule one is "SecRule REQUEST_BASENAME" @beginsWith / url_to_A "" id: 1, ctl: ruleEngine = Off "
The second rule is "SecRule REQUEST_BASENAME" @beginsWith / url_to_B "" id: 2, ctl: ruleEngine = Off ""